# Can systemd do some setup before forking as a user?

Tags: systemd, daemon, access-control

Having written several small daemons or web applications for my personal use, I like to manage them using systemd (I am using Arch Linux, if that matters). So I write service files like the one below:

```
[Unit]
Description=My example daemon

[Service]
Type=forking
User=example_user
ExecStart=/path/to/my_executable
ExecStop=kill -QUIT $MAINPID
PIDFile=/var/run/example/example.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

my_executable fails to start if it cannot write its PID file, which generally means that the directory `/var/run/example/` does not exist. This happens after every reboot since I have `/var/run` of a tempfs.

One solution is to start my_executable as root and have it drop to the correct access rights after creating its environment, but I not really comfortable with that, since I don't trust myself to do it correctly.

Is there a way to make systemd do the heavy lifting here (maybe by specifying another script that should run before doing ExecStart)? What is the best way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`systemd` provides [`systemd-tmpfiles`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles.html) for this exact purpose. The `systemd-tmpfiles` service handles the creation, cleaning and removal of volatile and temporary files and directories which usually reside in directories such as `/run` or `/tmp`. The configuration of `systemd-tmpfiles` is described in the [manual page of `tmpfiles.d`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html)<sup>1</sup>.

Create a `systemd-tmpfiles` configuration file for your service in one of the configuration paths, e.g. `etc/tmpfiles.d`. The format of the configuration file is one line per path, of the form:

```
type path mode ownership age argument
```

For instance, the line

```
d /var/run/example 0755 example_user - -
```

tells `systemd-tmpfiles` to create the directory `/var/run/example` owned by `example_user` if doesn't already exist.

<sup>1 The [Arch Linux wiki article on `systemd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Temporary_files) also provides some examples regarding `systemd-tmpfiles` configuration.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

For your exact situation, the service file would look something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My example daemon

[Service]
Type=forking
User=example_user
# Run ExecStartPre with root permissions
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=-/bin/mkdir /var/run/example
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R example_user /var/run/example/
# Run ExecStart with example_user permissions
ExecStart=/path/to/my_executable
ExecStop=kill -QUIT $MAINPID
PIDFile=/var/run/example/example.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

([source](https://blog.hqcodeshop.fi/archives/93-Handling-varrun-with-systemd.html))

Note: you might want to check the paths to `chown` and to `mkdir` first.